# How to deal with "SOCKS5 TTL expired" error?

Tags: configuration, socks

I use privoxy in combination with Tor. Sometimes when I visit a website I get the following error:

```
127.0.0.1: SOCKS5 TTL expired
```

How can I stop this from happening? In most cases it gets fixed by restarting Tor but that is not ideal.

Comment: Does not your system time change considerably while the Tor client is running?

Comment: No, it just counts as normal(as time does).

Comment: Are you visiting clearnet sites or hidden services?

Comment: Clearnet sites.

Comment: I usually just hit Reload and the site comes up sooner or later. Though I haven't yet investigated exactly why this is happening.

Answer (score 5):

What is happening is that Tor is returning the SOCKS error code `SOCKS5_TTL_EXPIRED` (0x06) as a result of a stream being closed for reason `END_STREAM_REASON_TIMEOUT`. There are many potential reasons why this might be happening but to find out which stream is timing out, and why, you should try enabling logging at level INFO.

Most likely, the circuit you are using is going through one or more overloaded nodes and so your client is not getting a response in time. Alternatively there may be a problem with DNS resolution at the exit node you are using. If you are accessing a hidden service then there are more nodes in the circuit so it is more likely this error will be triggered.

Retrying the request should normally clear this problem and it should not require restarting Tor – if a stream is failing then the circuit selected should be marked as unusable. If the problem keeps occurring until Tor gets restarted then it could be a bug and would be interesting to investigate further.